# How can I improve the performance of my code using redis

Tags: vb.net, stackexchange.redis

I installed Redis on my machine (Windows 7 64bit) then write the following code

```
Private Sub ReadDta()
    Dim Conn As ConnectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost")
    Dim redis As IDatabase = Conn.GetDatabase

    Dim lObjConnection As New SqlConnection(gStrConnectionString)
    lObjConnection.Open()

    Dim lStrQuery = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[AggregarTest_2M]"

    Dim SqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(lStrQuery, lObjConnection)
    Dim lObjDataReader As SqlDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

    If lObjDataReader IsNot Nothing Then

        For cnt As Integer = 0 To 2000000 - 1
            lObjDataReader.Read()

            'Loop throug each column (Total columns: 20) to create redis list against 'each column and save its value
            For count = 1 To 20 - 1               
                Dim colName = lObjDataReader.GetName(count)                   
                Dim val = lObjDataReader(colName)

                redis.ListRightPush(colName.ToString, val.ToString)
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This is taking too much time to execute.

Following is my Redis Installation

[Redis Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn4mB.png)

Do I missing some thing either in Redis installation or in my code

Comment: This might be more suited to Code Review

Comment: It appears your code is not complete. Please provide something complete enough to be able to test it vs. any alternative solutions. Explaining what it should be doing would also be helpful (along with any expected input and output). As Bugs said, review of functional code is often more appropriate on [codereview.se].

Comment: The first thing to speed up would be to ask if you really need 2 millions records with 20 data point each.